# Route-based VPN on Windows

Tags: windows, vpn

Is there a software VPN client on Windows that can handle route-based connections? That is, the software directs only traffic to specified domains over the VPN while the rest uses non-VPN interfaces. I know this can be done on Linux with iptables.

Ideally I would like a free (in cost) application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean routing based on IP addresses, then Windows can do it by itself:

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.1.2.3 if 3
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 if 2
```

where `10.1.2.3` is the gateway, and `if 3`/`if 2` are interface indexes as shown by `route print`.

I don't think you can route based on the DNS domain names, though.

Comment: How would this work with a software based VPN running on a local machine?

Comment: @user: Could you explain "software based VPN"?

Comment: e.g. Cisco AnyConnect, Shrew Soft VPN and Microsoft's built-in VPN client

Comment: @user: I have never used the first two; but the built-in VPN client of Windows should work just fine. Each VPN connection has a virtual network interface to which you can route stuff. (Same with OpenVPN.)

Comment: Thanks. Being unable to use domain names is problematic but maybe I will be lucky and my hosts will have static addresses.